# How to listen some var from another class without reference in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

When I developed android app with Java I used [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) , then I used `java.util.observable` to listen some var without getting a reference of a class/service.
For example, I could listen in ViewModel/Activity some var from a service without getting instance of that service.

I did it before I started using Clean Architecture, SOLID, MVVM etc.
Now I am using widely LiveData and ViewModel pattern, and Dependency Injection with Dagger2. So, every time I have a reference to listen a LiveData var.

I am wandering if exist in Kotlin a way to listen a var in one class from another class without getting an another class's reference?

This is not practical question, it's just curiosity

Comment: In Android, I'd recommend ViewModel/LiveData or maybe something coroutines-based.

Answer (score 1):

For listening to data from a variable just use LiveData.
wrap your variable in LiveData and use an observer to observe data changes to it.
Also if your variable is somewhere in a class which you don't want to create object of. Then you can simply wrap that variable in companion object like this.

```
class Test() {
  companion object {
    var testvariable = "Hello"
  }
}
```

then simply call it like this "Test.testvariable"